# Is there any way to be notified when an app is uninstalled from macOS using a Cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want my app to react when **some other** system app is uninstalled (not when mine is). Is there any intended Cocoa approach to this? If not, is there a reliable, if not intended, way to do this?

I do have a list of the most interesting ones to observe so a solution that is limited to a specific other app is fine, but a general solution would be great. Language is also not too much of an issue; Objective-C and Swift are the easiest, but if it must be scripted, that's fine, too.

I tried to find this out myself but [my](https://www.google.com/search?q=objective-c+cocoa+alert+app+uninstalled) [Google-fu](https://www.google.com/search?q=cocoa+uninstall+notification) [failed](https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+app+run+code+on+uninstall) [me](https://www.google.com/search?q=cocoa+listen+for+uninstall).

Answer (score 3):

Mac applications aren't really "installed" like on some other systems.  They're just bundles, which the user can run from anywhere.

If you have a specific .app filename to observe, you could set up an [NSMetadataQuery](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmetadataquery) to watch for changes to it, and receive a notification when the user moves it to the trash.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `-[NSWorkspace URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:]`. Or `LSCopyApplicationURLsForBundleIdentifier` in the case of multiple versions with the same bundle id. But it would be a pulling like implementation not a notification based one.

The bundle identifier could also be used with the `NSMetadataQuery` via  `kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier` predicate.